# Express excitement about something possible in future

Tags: word-usage, auxiliary-verbs

I want to say that I am excited to join school X, but at the same time, I want to tell that I might not be accepted there. Saying "I am very excited to join X" implicit that school X accepted me and joining X is definitely going to occur, doesn't? Does "I would/might be very excited to join X" do the job here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you'd better use "I would be excited" in this case.

"I might be excited" sounds like you are not sure if the acceptance would make you happy/excited or not. You know you would be excited, you just don't know if you can be accepted. So, use "would" instead of "might".